# Chained textbox in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Want to create chained textbox :

```
textbox1            textbox2             textbox3
_________           ____________       _____________
|___A____|         |(1)disabled|       |(a)disabled|

textbox1(value):A,B,C,D,E; 
textbox2(value):1,2,3,4,5; 
textbox3(value):a,b,c,d,e; like-> "A,1,a","B,2,b"=> this will be the combination
```

Where selecting the value of textbox1,corresponding value to textbox1 will appear in textbox2,so as in textbox3 w.r.t textbox3.And my predefined value will be stored in jQuery function,on calling it will fill the value.

Suggestion.... needed

Comment: do you mean `selectBox` or `textArea`, try to improve you aceept rate

Comment: Hiya, You should really think of improving your accept ratio, and please attach some code as well that usually help us to help you man, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".chainbox").on("keyup", function(){
    $(".chainbox").val(this.value);
});​
```

**[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/hGfAH/2/)**

I think you want a `selectbox` instead of `checkbox` (not sure)

```
$(".myselect").on("change", function(){

    // here I update value of next select box 
    // using current selectbox value
    // may be you have something else

    $(this).next('.myselect').val(this.value).prop('disabled', false);
});​
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/L5MF3/2/)**

If you want to show the selected text of first select to next two text box then:

```
$(".myselect").on("change", function(){
    $(this).nextAll(':input.mytext').val($('option:selected', this).text());
});
```

**[DEMO 3](http://jsfiddle.net/L5MF3/7/)**

Comment: It seems to me he want the **selected** text in textbox 1 to show up in textbox 2 and 3. No?

Comment: >thecodeparadox : I want textbox (in 3 cases)

Comment: @Vivekanand then first demo should work for you

Comment: @Vivekanand don't understand anything? describe in your question everything, not in comment

Comment: @Vivekanand what wrong with my answer? may i know

Answer (score 1):

**working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Mwkjs/10/

Please let me know if I missed anything.

So you can use `change` or `keydown` apis as well.

Hope this help!

**jquery code**

```
$(".foo").on("keyup",function(){
    $(".foo").val($(this).val());
});​
```